# JQuery animate() with easing plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-easing

**SOLVED** Thanks everyone for help inccorrect path to plugin is so unnecessary error...

Hi I have problem with using JQuery easing plugin with animate() function in Jquery. I am searching on web and I not found solution yet.

My code is working with default type of easing in animation function (for example switch), but when I change type of easing then script stop his work.

My code is like:

```
<script src="funkce/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="funkce/lightbox/jquery.animation.easing.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

> ```
> before this script I test 
> <script src="funkce/lightbox/jquery.easing.1.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
> and after that <script src="funkce/lightbox/jquery.easing.1.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
> ```

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#slider" ).hover(function(){
if ($("#test1").css('display') == 'block'){
      $("#block").animate({ 
        "opacity": "0.6",
        "top": "200px"
      }, {queue:false, duration: 4000, easing:"easeOutElastic"} );
    }
    else{
        $( "#block" ).css({ top: ""});
      }
    });

  });
  </script>
```

(when I remove " easing:"easeOutElastic" " then code work with default type of easing.

Another try was:

```
if ($("#test1").css('display') == 'block'){
      $("#block").animate({ 
        opacity: 0.6,
        top: "200px"
      }, 4000, "easeOutElastic" );
    }
    else{
        $( "#block" ).css({ top: ""});
      }
    });
```

There when I remove " "easeOutElastic" " then vode works.

Still same problem in all my types of code still default easing works and alternative easing which support me easing plugin then code not work. This example I try add to nivoslider for some specific effect, but I now only test easing before I make my work.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is the path to `funkce/lightbox/jquery.animation.easing.js` correct? Can you confirm it is being loaded?

Comment: What have you tried? Are there any errors in the console? Are you sure the script is actually loaded correctly?

Comment: Hmmm it is so simple this path is incorrect.... I get this link from including prettyfoto and I have this plugin in another folder. Thank for help. :)